# Is this an instance of a Diffie-Hellman problem?

Tags: diffie-hellman, discrete-logarithm, hardness-assumptions

Let $\mathbb{G}$ be a cyclic group of order $p$ with generator $g$, and let $m\in\mathbb{G}$.

**Problem**: Given $c=m.g^{k.a}$ and $v=g^a$, where $k,a \in \mathbb{Z}^*_p$, output $k$.

Is this an instance of a Diffie-Hellman problem? Because the only way I see to solve this is to try $v^i, i\in \mathbb{Z}^*_p$ until we *stumble* on $i=k$, but since $g^{k.a}$ is also hidden by $m$, I do not think searching for $i$ is a viable method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated the problem is insoluble as zero-knowledge of $k$ is provided (unless we know something about $m$).

To see this, let $x$ be any integer $0\le x\le p-1$ and let $m':= m\cdot v^{-x}$ then we see that $c=m'\cdot g^{(k+x)a}$ and we see that $k+x\pmod p$ is an equally valid output unless we have some reason to choose $m$ over $m'$.

Comment: So, If I understood correctly, using your approach, we can get $k$ if we are able to *deduce* m. Thank you

Comment: More precisely we have enough information to get $k$ if we are able to deduce $m$. From $c/m=g^{ka}=v^k$ we are able to recover $k$ if we can solve the discrete logarithm problem in $G$. This may or may not be computationally feasible.